# SQL : update statement with dynamic column value assignment

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Imagine the following sql query:

```
UPDATE MYTABLE
SET COL2 = (SELECT COL2 + 1 FROM (SELECT MAX(COL2) FROM MYTABLE) AS X)
WHERE ID IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Assume that before the update is executed MAX(COL2) is 1.

My intention is that for the update where ID=1 COL2 is updated to 'max(COL2) + 1'  (i.e. 2), and that for subsequent updates  'MAX(COL2) + 1' is re-evaluated, so that for ID=2, COL2=3 and ID=3, COL2=4  etc...

What actually happens is that for all rows (ID=1,2,3,4,5), the value of COL2 is 2.

Is there a smart way to have the  value of MAX(COL2) +1 "re-evaluated" at each update? I realize there may be performance issues with doing this, but I am curious none-the-less! Is there a better alternative (that does not involve multiple update statements) ?

BTW: incase you are wondering about the syntax used for the above query (the nested inner table) see here: [SQL : Using the target table in an UPDATE statement in a nested FROM clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556237/sql-using-the-target-table-in-an-update-statement-in-a-nested-from-clause)

Comment: Please post what you have now in your table and what you want to see as a result.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
UPDATE mytable, (
  SELECT @loop := MAX(col1)
  FROM
    mytable
  ) o
SET col1 = (@loop := @loop + 1)
```

What you encountered here is called `query stability`.

No query can see the changes made by itself, or the following query:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET col1 = col2 + 1
WHERE col1 > col2
```

would never end.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the way I'd do it:

```
SELECT MAX(col2) FROM mytable INTO @max;

UPDATE mytable
SET col2 = @max:=@max+1
WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
ORDER BY id;
```

I tested this on MySQL 5.1.30 and it works.

I set the `@max` variable first just because I find @Quassnoi's trick of doing it in a Cartesian product to be unnecessary and less readable.

Note that MySQL supports `ORDER BY` in an `UPDATE` statement (this is not standard SQL), and you should do this, to ensure the values are updated in the order you want.  Otherwise MySQL guarantees no specific order.

Comment: This works too! But since I am executing the query as a single statement via jdbc I'll go with @Quassnoi's.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @loop int
select @loop = 1

UPDATE MYTABLE
SET COL1 = @loop,
    @loop = @loop+1
WHERE ID IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

> > Is there a smart way to have the value of MAX(COL1) +1 "re-evaluated" at each insert?

Not unless you update the rows one-by-one :(

This would work in MSSQL, dunno about MySQL, but might give you an idea:

```
DECLARE @Counter int

SELECT @Counter = MAX(COL2) FROM MYTABLE

UPDATE MYTABLE
SET @Counter = @Counter + 1,
    COL1 = @Counter
WHERE ID IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

EDIT: I think the SET statement can be simplified in MSSQL to:

```
SET @Counter = COL1 = @Counter + 1
```

Answer (score -1):

<strike>It should be re-evaluating it at each insert; presumably the max of COL2 is not changing. Are you sure you don't want to select MAX(COL**1**)?</strike>
Reading your question again, you mixed up the terms insert and update (which is now fixed), and I got thrown for a loop.

---

You're trying to update many records at once but have it act as if it's updating each individually. This will not work as you're intending.

You could create a stored procedure to loop through each record WHERE ID IN (1,2,3,4,5) and update individually. Or, since you're only doing 5 rows, why not just copy and paste the statement five times and change the WHERE clause to `WHERE ID = 1` (and 2, 3, 4, 5 on subsequent lines).

Comment: "unless your brand of SQL doesn't like it?" I believe in MySQL that a nested SELECT in an UPDATE has to be double-wrapped.

I think your solution will assign the same MAX(COL2) value to all 5 rows in the update

Comment: Apparently so, presuming the "BTW" link in the original post is correct.

Comment: @lc : In answer to "As a side note, why are you casting the MAX(COL2) to a temp table and selecting from it again?"  Please read the posting in it's entirety (including the final BTW)

Comment: Yeah I caught that. Note the "Apparently so" and my edit. Sorry for missing that the first (and second) time through.